# Web2py - Using a Gmail address

Tags: gmail, web2py, email-address

I am beginner with web2py. I have just created a new project.

I want to use a gmail address, let's say g@gmail.com. What do I need to modify ?

```
mail.settings.server = 'logging' or 'smtp.gmail.com:587'  # your SMTP server
mail.settings.sender = 'g@gmail.com'         # your email
mail.settings.login = 'g@gmail.com:mypassword'      # your credentials or None
```

Is this OK ?
What is the purpose of `'logging'` ?

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
```

Setting mail.settings.server = 'logging' has the effects of logging to console requests for sending emails but does not send the emails. It is useful for debugging email problems.